# Using ArcGIS Field Calculator to change text to digit?

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

I have one field that is titled SEVERITY, and is string type, and has words like "Medium" "Low" "High," etc.  I would like to assign a number to correspond with the word ("1" for "Low", 2 for "Medium," etc.), and to have that populate in a new field.

I've created the new field, called it "SEVERITY_CODE" and made it an integer.  All I need to do is use the field calculator to say "look at the SEVERITY column, and translate that into numbers for the "SEVERITY_CODE" column but I cannot seem to find it.  The solutions I've found on the web are not helping.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like (using python):

```
def calc(SEVERITY_CODE):
    if SEVERITY == "Low":
        return 1
    elif SEVERITY == "Medium":
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

Examples: [Writing conditional (if/then) statements into Field Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop using Python parser?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99615/writing-conditional-if-then-statements-into-field-calculator-of-arcgis-for-des) and [Use Python in ArcGIS Field Calculator to return value based on numeric value in any of three other fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256479/use-python-in-arcgis-field-calculator-to-return-value-based-on-numeric-value-in/256480)